# VB.NET and DSharpPlus .. Awaiting/Async

Tags: vb.net, discord

I am using DSHARPPLUS (for Discord) in my VB.NET application. I've wrapped the messages coming from discord with a handler (which is a async handler):

```
AddHandler DiscordGuild.MessageCreated, AddressOf MessageRecievedFromDiscord
```

.. I then use it like so:

```
Public Async Function MessageRecievedFromDiscord(sender As DiscordClient, e As MessageCreateEventArgs) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Await Task.Delay(0)
    If e.Author.IsBot Then Return True
    If e.Channel.IsPrivate Then Return True

    Dim channel As ULong = e.Message.ChannelId
    If channel = mainGlobalChannel Then
        If e.Message.Content.ToLower().StartsWith("!mute") Then
            'Do Stuff here
            Return True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

My question is, does this run ASYNC properly? Is this even right? I want the messages to be handled off the main thread obviously. I am not sure if it really is. (Often lately my bot seems to be disconnecting and I wonder if it has to do with the way it's handling messages, it will just send the message using something like `DiscordGuild.SendMessageAsync(queueOut.channel, queueOut.message)`

which should work anyways.

Thanks!

Comment: The only `async` thing is just the delay, which being 0 means no delay (hence nothing async at all), so there is no need to put any `async`/`await` at all (unless the "Do Stuff here" part does something async).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What it does is send out a message normally with DiscordGuild.SendMessageAsync() . How would I get this to be async? I don't want it clogging up the main thread generally.  Would I have in something like this in MessageRecievedFromDiscord:

await Task.Run(() => HandleMessage(e As MessageCreateEventArgs));

And add that as the code, making handlemessage work as a new thread?

Comment: If there aren't any `async` calls in the event handler, then there is nothing to worry about, since you aren't doing anything that would clog the UI. Again, the **Do Stuff here** part is key here.

Comment: When I try to remove the async I get this error:  Error BC31143 Method 'Public Sub MessageRecievedFromDiscord(sender As DiscordClient, e As MessageCreateEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Function AsyncEventHandler(Of DiscordClient, MessageCreateEventArgs)(sender As DiscordClient, e As MessageCreateEventArgs) As Task'. 

Mind you 'MessageCreated' isn't something I made, it's from the DiscordBot dll file itself. Sorry should of been more specific there!

Comment: Don't make it a sub. Make it a `Public Function MessageRecievedFromDiscord(sender As DiscordClient, e As MessageCreateEventArgs) As Task(Of Boolean)` and return `Task.FromResult(True)`.

Comment: Ah okay! That did work then, thanks!